# Why am I not able to add a new project for enabling Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-developers-console

For some reason, I can't seem to just add a new project.  I've been at this for days now and getting nowhere with it.  I need to enable the Drive API for a client in order to create the keys needed to connect to their drive for the purpose of storing backups from a web application.  I've done this a few times before but have never had the sort of issues I'm having now.

In the Google Developers Console, Libraries tab, I select Drive API > Enable > Create.  From there I enter a project name and click Create.  This is where everything stops working.  A modal will pop up with a spinner that just spins forever.

[image]

Almost immediately afterwards, I receive a notification in the Google Developers Console that there was unknown error.

[image]

I've cleared caches & cookies, flushed socket pools, restarted Chrome, updated Chrome, tried different browsers, etc., but to no avail.

The only error I get in DevTools is a 403 (forbidden) when I click the "Enable" button after selecting the Drive API from the Developers Console.

[image]

I've searched message boards and status pages for clues that others may be experiencing the same problem but without any luck.  At first I thought that this might be some internal issue with Google Drive or G Suites, but it has been several days and I think issues like this would have had more attention by now if it were widespread.  Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: I also have this error trying to create a google maps api key at https://console.developers.google.com  There appears to be at least one bug report about this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67282849

Comment: Appears to be resolved now. I was finally able to create a project

Comment: I'm still having the same problem, even weeks later.