# Unknown error when creating a new project in Google API

Tags: google-api, developer-console

I am getting this error when I try to create a project in [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com). I have 8 more projects left in my quota. I have tried different names and different project IDs. When I hit the "retry" button it shows the error after some time again.

[image: Google API project creation error in Chrome]

**UPDATE *[Oct 9, 2017]*:** It looks like Google fixed the issue, since I was able to create a new project today.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429070/why-am-i-not-able-to-add-a-new-project-for-enabling-drive-api appears to talk about this as well, no resolution there (at time of writing comment)

Comment: @AdamErstelle, it looks like it's working now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and attempted to create a new project in the Google API, and received the same error. This has occurred before with the Google API and is considered a temporary issue, often being fixed the same day. But if I remember correctly they have had it down longer in the past.

So the good news is, it's not something that is on your end, the bad news is, it's on Google's end.

Answer (score 0):

If your google account is a Google Apps account (Google Suite, Google Apps, Gsuite, or whatever the Marketing folks are calling it these days), then you need to enable "Google Developers Console".

> 1. Login as an admin to admin.google.com
> 2. Go to Apps > Additional Google services
> 3. Find the "Google Developers Console" line item and set to "ON for everyone" (or whatever).

That should do it.